# What's the best way to pipeline this and filter?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I just wanted to filter the names of the information from Get-ChildItem`.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Users

$folders.Name -like '*test*'
```

What's the best way to do that instead of writing these two lines?

What is the term for the `.Name` called?

Comment: Really @ansgarweichers ?  Putting (get-childitem) in the header is fluffy?

Answer (score 2):

Name is a property.  There's so many ways:

```
get-childitem c:\users\*test*
get-childitem c:\users *test* # filter
get-childitem c:\users | where name -like *test*
get-childitem c:\users | where name -match test
(get-childitem c:\users).name -like '*test*' # doesn't stream as well
```

Comment: To elaborate.. only because I feel it is important for beginners to test things like this.. if you do `$folders | Get-Member` you will be shown a list of, well, members for that object. Members include properties, methods, etc.. It's just good info to help you write more efficient code.  You can do `$anyObject | Get-Member` to view members. TheMoreYouKnow.gif

Comment: @MattOestreich I like `$var | fl *`.  fl is short for format-list.  I'm not disagreeing.  But that's what I do most of the time.

Comment: For sure, definitely good if you want to see property values - all in all `Format-List` and `Get-Member` is not apples to apples.. `Get-Member` will show you all members and their types (outside of just properties) - `Format-List` will show you properties and their values.  `Format-List` is more useful in the 'wild', while `Get-Member` helps you better understand the objects you're working with, from under the hood - it isn't as concerned with current property values, more so about 'what types of properties does this object have'?  Cheers!

Comment: "*The Best way to pipeline*" is quiet relative in this context. Nevertheless, I would remove the last suggestion `(get-childitem c:\users).name -like '*test*'` as the use of brackets, `(...)`, will simply choke the pipeline.

Comment: @iRon This works for me:  `(get-childitem c:\users).name -like '*' | measure`

Comment: I know it works, but it isn't a good way **to pipeline**. By using parentheses, you first collecting all the childitems (and increase memory usage) and than after that, start building a pipeline containing all the name properties. Meaning, if you have a long list of childitems you will notice that it will take a while (and an increase of memory usage) before it outputs which is not the case in the other suggestions.

Comment: @iron I understand.  I added a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For the better solution in your example is

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users -filter "*test*"
```

because the filter is directly in the first command and not after pipe, then better in performance

If you want only found files or only directories, dont forget to use -file vs -directory in the Get-ChildItem command ;)

Comment: You're right about -filter being faster.  My only caveat is that in PS 5, -filter matches the *short version of the filename*.  `cmd /c dir /x; dir -filter *~1*
`

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question, I think it is important to define **why** you want to **use the pipeline**.
For this I can see two major reasons:

1. increase performance
2. decrease memory usage

Although the first reason (performance) is in most cases the drive behind using the pipeline, it is not always the quickest way, simply loading everything into memory and than performing an action on it will be in a lot of cases quicker than using the pipeline.

**So, when is using the pipeline quicker?**
A pipeline is usually quicker if you have a slow input source or output destination because you using the wait time (until the next item is received or accepted) to work ahead and process the rest of the items that are at hand.

Taking your question as an example:
Let say you have **1000** items (files) to process and it takes **10 ms** to retrieve an item (file from the disk) and **5 ms** to filter it. If you do not use te pipeline it will take `1000 * 10 + 1000 * 5 =` **15000 ms** to process and if you do use the pipeline, it will only take `1000 * 10 + 5 =` **10005 ms** to process because you already process (filter and release) the other **999** items in the same time you are waiting for each next item to be received.
<sub>Note: that this will probably not be a good example because the files are likely cached and very fast delivered, but it will be a different story if they would come from remote location.</sub>

(With this in mind, I would like to change the question:)

### What's *not* a good way to pipeline this and filter?

There are actually two main PowerShell programming techniques that will choke the pipeline:

1. When you assign the pipeline to a variable.
   As in your question: <strike>`$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Users`</strike>
2. Using parentheses.
   <strike>`(Get-ChildItem C:\Users) | ...`</strike> (were you actually do a anonymous assignment.)

In other words, for **the best way to pipeline this and filter?**:
Use the pipe character (`|`) and try to avoid using any assignments or parentheses as this will pile up all the items in the pipeline into memory.