# Pipeline in Powershell

Tags: powershell, pipeline, sort-object

I was reading about how pipeline works in PowerShell at [about_Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=A%20pipeline%20is%20a%20series,sent%20to%20yet%20another%20command), and got to know that pipeline delivers one object at a time.

So, this

```
Get-Service | Format-Table -Property Name, DependentServices
```

Is different from this

```
Format-Table -InputObject (Get-Service) -Property Name, DependentServices
```

So here, going by the explanation, in the first case, the `Format-Table` works on one object at at time and in the second example, `Format-Table` works on an array of objects. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If this is the case, then I wonder how does `Sort-Object` and other cmdlets that need to work on collections of data work with pipe character.

When I do :

```
Get-Service | Sort-Object
```

How is `Sort-Object` able to sort if it just gets to work with one object at a time. So, assume there are 100 service objects that are to be passed to `Sort-Object`. Will `Sort-Object` be called 100 times (each for one object) ? And, How will that yield in Sorted results that I see on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sort-Object` (and other cmdlets that need to evaluate *all* input objects before outputting anything) work by collecting the input objects one by one, and then not doing any actual work until the upstream cmdlet (`Get-Service` in this case) is done sending input.

How does this work? Well, let's try and recreate `Sort-Object` with a PowerShell function.

To do so, we first need to understand that a cmdlet consists of 3 separate routines:

- `Begin` - the `Begin` routines of each cmdlet in a pipeline are invoked *once* before anything else occurs
- `Process` - this routine is invoked on each cmdlet *every time input is received* from an upstream command
- `End` - this is invoked once the upstream command has called `End` and there are no more input items for `Process` to process

(These are the block label names used in PowerShell *function* definitions - in a binary cmdlet you'd override the implementation of [`BeginProcessing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.beginprocessing), [`ProcessRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.processrecord), [`EndProcessing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.endprocessing) methods of your cmdlet)

So, to "collect" every input item, we need to add some logic to the `Process` block of our command, and then we can put the code that operates on all the items in the `End` block:

```
function Sort-ObjectCustom
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [object[]]$InputObject
  )

  begin {
    # Let's use the `begin` block to create a list that'll hold all the input items
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

    Write-Verbose "Begin was called"
  }

  process {
    # Here we simply collect all input to our list
    $list.AddRange($InputObject)

    Write-Verbose "Process was called [InputObject: $InputObject]"
  }

  end {
    # The `end` block is only ever called _after_ we've collected all input
    # Now we can safely sort it
    $list.Sort()

    Write-Verbose "End was called"

    # and output the results
    return $list
  }
}
```

If we invoke our new command with `-Verbose`, we will see how the input is collected one by one:

```
PS ~> 10..1 |Sort-ObjectCustom -Verbose
VERBOSE: Begin was called
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 10]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 9]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 8]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 7]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 6]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 5]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 4]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 3]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 2]
VERBOSE: Process was called [InputObject: 1]
VERBOSE: End was called
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

For more information on how to implement pipeline input processing routines for binary cmdlets, see the ["How to Override Input Processing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-override-input-processing-methods).

For more information on how to take advantage of the same pipeline semantics in functions, see the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Methods` and related help topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods)

Comment: Thank you. Nicely explained. That clears many doubts. If I may ask, can you also explain how, whatever is written on left side of pipe character is handled? So, when microsoft says that pipe delivers object one by one, does it mean that Get-Service would be invoked many times while maintaining some state and it would emit object one by one for Sort-Object's process to capture or does it mean that Get-Service would be invoked once, and the collection would be kept somewhere in buffer and pipe would make sure to deliver the object one at a time?

Comment: Well, `Get-Service` will _also_ do most of it's work in the `End` block, and once the `End` block returns, the pipeline processor (the "PowerShell engine" responsible for execution of the pipeline) will know that `Get-Service` is "done". Does that make sense?

Comment: @pragun It's important to understand that any of the 3 routines can output 1 object, multiple objects, or none at all - completely up to the author of the command. There's no hard-and-fast rule that all output has to be sent in either `process` or `end` for example

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Yes, that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer from [**Mathias**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), you can actually visualize the order of the process from an existing cmdlet using the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) cmdlet which immediately writes the output to the display (rather than the pipeline):

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Id, Name
 4, Four
 2, Two
 3, Three
 1, One
'@
```

#### `Select-Object` example

```
$Data |
    Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'in:' ($_ |ConvertTo-Json -Compress); $_ } |
    Select-Object * |
    Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'out:' ($_ |ConvertTo-Json -Compress); $_ }
```

**Shows:**

```
in: {"Id":"4","Name":"Four"}
out: {"Id":"4","Name":"Four"}

in: {"Id":"2","Name":"Two"}
out: {"Id":"2","Name":"Two"}
in: {"Id":"3","Name":"Three"}
out: {"Id":"3","Name":"Three"}
in: {"Id":"1","Name":"One"}
out: {"Id":"1","Name":"One"}
Id Name
-- ----
4  Four
2  Two
3  Three
1  One
```

#### `Sort-Object` example

```
$Data |
    Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'in:' ($_ |ConvertTo-Json -Compress); $_ } |
    Sort-Object * |
    Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'out:' ($_ |ConvertTo-Json -Compress); $_ }
```

**Shows:**

```
in: {"Id":"4","Name":"Four"}
in: {"Id":"2","Name":"Two"}
in: {"Id":"3","Name":"Three"}
in: {"Id":"1","Name":"One"}
out: {"Id":"1","Name":"One"}

out: {"Id":"2","Name":"Two"}
out: {"Id":"3","Name":"Three"}
out: {"Id":"4","Name":"Four"}
Id Name
-- ----
1  One
2  Two
3  Three
4  Four
```

In general, PowerShell cmdlets [Write Single Records to the Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#write-single-records-to-the-pipeline-sc03) where it is possible (one of the advantages of this encouraged guideline is that it reduces memory consumption). As implied by your question, [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) can't do this because the last record might possibly come before the first record. But there are also exceptions where it would be technically possible to write single records according the encouraged guideline, but it is not. See e.g.: [`#11221` Select-Object -Unique is unnecessary slow and exhaustive](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221)

Comment: Awesome. So, it's the implementation of cmdlets (in the Begin/Process/End block) that matters based on which powershell decides the order of execution. Thank you!!
I have been looking at some of the stuff that powershell is able to do and I am just blown away with the merits of this .NET Objects Based Shell. Strong Oops with the flexibility of shell scripting language. I doubt that there is any alternative to this. Bash feels too primitive and naive in front of it. And yet people hail "bash" as some angel and undermine anything microsoft does just for the heck of it.

Comment: The `Select-Object` example is confusing, because the only reason the tabular output doesn't appear until later is unrelated to actual output sequencing: it is solely due to the infamous 300-msec. delay - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375

Comment: Is there anyway to tell which cmdlets collect input before processing? I'm trying to determine where a pipeline is slowing down and whether I can rewrite it to remain in the pipeline or just need to overhaul everything. Off the top of my head, I can think of `Sort-`, `Group-`, but is there an exhaustive list of which cmdlets do or don't collect input upfront and under what scenarios? (e.g. `Import-Csv` you can pipe out if you want so it doesn't by necessity)

Comment: @immobile2, afaik, there is no list of what cmdlets choke the pipeline. In general, all standard PowerShell cmdlets are [implemented for the Middle of a Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline) unless that is not possible by its (parameter) defintion (e.g `Sort-Object` were the last object might become first). Also note that using parentheses or assinging a pipeline will choke the pipeline, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57232847/1701026).