# Sort-Object -inputObject

Tags: powershell, performance, syntax, pipeline, sort-object

I can sort an array using the pipeline, like this `$array | Sort-object`
However, I have found that the pipeline is SLOW, and mostly makes sense in quick one liners. But when writing a program, or even a quick script, I find it's better to not use the pipeline, for both readability and performance reasons. So I went to SS64 and found [this](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html) page on `Sort-Object` with mention of the
`-InputObject` parameter. And I would have thought that `Sort-Object -InputObject:$array` would be the same. But no, that page specifically says of `-InputObject`

> The objects to be sorted.
>
> When the `-InputObject` parameter is used to submit a collection of items,
> `Sort-Object` receives one object that represents the collection.
> Because one object cannot be sorted, `Sort-Object` returns the entire collection unchanged.
>
> To sort objects, pipe them to `Sort-Object`.

So, what on earth is `-InputObject` for then? It seems like the only possible use case is the one that doesn't work.
And, IS there a way to use `Sort-Object` on an existing array, without resorting to the pipeline?

Comment: `InputObject` is there to allow for pipeline binding - try running `Trace-Command -Expression {1..3 |Sort-Object} -Name *bind* -PSHost` and review the output on the screen :)

Comment: `[linq.enumerable]::OrderByDescending()` and `[linq.enumerable]::OrderBy()` may be faster for sorting certain data sets

Comment: Also, *does it matter that it's slow*? Sorting is something you usually only do _once_ or a few times

Comment: Generally not for the workloads PowerShell is typically used for but it's good to know more performant alternatives for some use cases

Comment: Perhaps [this helps explain why `Sort-Object` works the way it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243578/pipeline-in-powershell/68243737#68243737)?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen True that performance isn't a major issue in lots of cases. It's more one of readability, so why not ALSO get a bit better performance, as well as better readability.

Comment: @Theo I'll need to look into the sort static method option. I am also using the -Unique flag with Sort-Object, but I could address that with a test to see if an item already exists before adding to the array, or just a try/catch with noting in the catch.

Answer (score 2):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68833812/45375) shows a **fast, in-place way to sort an array** that's already in memory and stored in a variable, using a .NET API.

If you want **to sort and also *eliminate duplicates*** (the equivalent of `Sort-Object -Unique`), you can use a [`System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet-1) instance:

```sh
PS> [System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]]::new(
      [string[]] ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'), 
      [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
    )

bar
baz
foo
```

<sup>Note: If you use `[object]` as `SortedSet`'s generic type argument, you don't need the `[string[]]` cast, but it's generally preferable to use specific types.</sup>

Note: The result isn't an *array*, but it can be enumerated like one with a `foreach` statement and in the pipeline. To copy the results to an array - such as when you need to apply indexing (e.g, `[0]`) -
preallocate a target array of the same type and use the `.CopyTo()` method to fill it (`$arr = [string[]]::new($sortedSet.Count); $sortedSet.CopyTo($arr)`)

An **alternative** is to sort the array with duplicates first, and then apply [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct) afterwards:

```sh
[string[]] $arr = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'
[Array]::Sort($arr, [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
[Linq.Enumerable]::Distinct($arr)
```

Note: The result is a *lazy enumerable*, not an array, but it can be enumerated like one with a `foreach` statement and in the pipeline. Call the `.ToArray()` method to create an array explicitly, such as when you need to apply indexing (e.g, `[0]`).

---

As for **your question**:

> So, what on earth is -InputObject for then?

**For the *majority* of cmdlets, unfortunately, the `-InputObject` parameter is just an *implementation detail*: its purpose is to enable input *via the pipeline***, and its direct use with *arrays* (collections) is pointless, such as in the case of `Sort-Object`.

- [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) asks that `-InputObject` be clearly documented as such, and also contain a list of cmdlets that *do* meaningfully support direct use of `-InputObject`, however, not as an *alternative* to pipeline input, but with *different semantics*, operating on an array (a collection) *as a whole* when `-InputObject` is used; e.g., `1, 'foo' | Get-Member` works (meaningfully) differently from `Get-Member -InputObject (1, 'foo')`: the former reports the types of the array's *elements*, the latter the type of the *array itself*.
- Among *data*-processing cmdlets (as opposed to *formatting* cmdlets), it is effectively only [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) and [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) (which in part is a formatting cmdlet as well) that support direct `-InputObject` use with arrays; e.g.:

  ```sh
  # Both commands produce the same output.
  1, 2 | Write-Output
  Write-Output -InputObject 1, 2
  ```

  - Even there, however the behavior differs with *nested* arrays, because the enumeration depths differ between the two methods:

    ```sh
    # NOT the same, due to nesting.
    1, (2, (3, 4)) | Write-Output # -> 1, 2, (3, 4)
    Write-Output -InputObject 1, (2, (3, 4)) # -> 1, (2, (3, 4))
    ```

**This non-support for direct, array-valued `-InputObject` argument is unfortunate, because it can greatly speed up things**, especially with data already in memory in full:

Bypassing the one-by-one streaming that invariably occurs in the pipeline (requiring a handshake of sorts between the sending and the receiving command *for each object*) - can greatly boost performance.

An example is the `-Value` parameter of the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet, which *does* accept direct array-valued arguments in lieu of pipeline input, and using `-Value` directly greatly speeds up the operation.

```sh
# Write 100,000 (1e5) numbers to a file:
# Via the pipeline.
1..1e5 | Set-Content temp.txt
# Via -Value - this is much, much faster.
# E.g. on my macOS machine with PowerShell 7.1, about 100(!) times faster.
Set-Content temp.txt -Value (1..1e5)
```

**Potential improvements**:

Note:

- A cmdlet is in theory free to implement its own array support for `-InputObject`, but that is (a) cumbersome, due to requiring extra logic, and (b) requires either declaring the parameter as an *array* type (which is inefficient, because even single objects received via the pipeline are then wrapped in arrays) or declaring it as `object`, which potentially forfeits type safety.

Ideally, **PowerShell *itself* should provide this support**, along the following lines:

- **Extend the [`[Parameter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) attribute
  with a new, Boolean `EnumerateArgument` property** that can be combined with the existing `ValueFromPipeline` and `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` properties, which, when set to `$true`, would instruct PowerShell:

  - to implicitly accept *arrays* of the specified (scalar) parameter type with *direct* use of the parameter, e.g., `[int[]]` for an `[int]`-typed parameter
  - and to *enumerate* those arrays *just like in the pipeline*, calling the cmdlet's `process` block (cmdlets (advanced functions) implemented in PowerShell) / `.ProcessRecord()` method (binary cmdlets) for each enumerated object.

A hypothetical (contrived) example:

```sh
function ConvertTo-Long {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    # WISHFUL THINKING: implicit array support for direct -InputObject arguments
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, EnumerateArgument)]
    [int] $InputObject
  )

  process {
    [long] $InputObject   
  }

}

# The following calls would then be equivalent:
1, 2, 3 | ConvertTo-Long
ConvertTo-Long -InputObject 1, 2, 3
```

Note:

- The improvement would be available to *any* pipeline-binding parameter (not just `-InputObject`).
- Arguably, `EnumerateArgument` should be `$true` *by default*, and that those rare cmdlets where passing an array as an argument has a *different meaning*, such as `Get-Member`, should *opt out* - however, that woulld be a *backward-compatibility concern*.
- Since the proposed enhancement would still involve calling the `process` block / the `.ProcessRecord()` method *for each enumerated object*, the speed-up won't be as dramatic as with a custom implementation that itself performs the enumeration in a *single* call. However, to me the prospect of unifying the behavior between the pipeline and direct `-InputObject` use alone makes this improvement worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is inside your $array, you can probably use .Net [Array.Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort) for faster performance when sorting the elements in a one-dimensional array.

```
[array]::Sort($array)
```

Type `[array]::Sort` without the brackets and hit enter to see all available OverloadDefinitions.

---

Good point by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68833304/sort-object-inputobject/68833812#comment121653995_68833812)

The above sorts case-sensitively, while PowerShell's `Sort-Object` works case-insensitively.

To have that same effect when using .Net `[array]::Sort()`, you can add a second parameter:

```
[array]::Sort($array, [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sort-Object -InputObject` is meant to be used from the pipeline, not invoked as a direct argument. Use `-InputObject` like so:

```
1, 5, 10, 3, 2 | Sort-Object # ==> 1, 2, 3, 5, 10
```

When you pass a collection via the pipeline, each element is *sent to the cmdlet as it becomes available*. The collection is unrolled and each element is processed individually by the cmdlet.

When you invoke the argument directly, the collection is not unrolled. so in the case of
`ForEach-Object` rather than sorting the several elements individually it sees a single object and returns just that object. Yes, it's a collection, but the cmdlet is designed to use the unrolling mechanic of the PowerShell pipeline, it is not designed to unroll the collection itself.

It can be a bit confusing, and to make it **clear as mud** many cmdlets work fine when the pipeline argument is directly invoked (often `-InputObject` but other names are also used). But as a rule of thumb if `-InputObject` (or whatever the `ValueFromPipeline` parameter is named) takes a collection, I invoke it using the pipeline.

---

If you want a faster sort method, you can use the [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0) static method instead:

```
[Array]::Sort($array)
```

`Array.ForEach` also performs faster than `ForEach-Object` or the `foreach` statement, and `Array.Where` performs better than `Where-Object`. The trade-off with using the `Array` static methods is you have a chink in the pipeline chain, as you can't pipe data *into* a .NET method.

---

To address your concern about relying on `Sort-Object -Unique`, you can pipe the result of `Array.Sort` to `Select-Object -Unique` instead. For example:

```
$myArray = 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 3, 8, 9

# Array.Sort sorts in-place so we need to sort the array, then uniqify it
[Array]::Sort($myArray)
$myArray | Select-Object -Unique
```

will output a sorted collection with unique values:

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
```