# Powershell Where-Object doesn't seem to filter

Tags: powershell, filter

I'm trying to do some reporting on Azure Policies. I'll eventually be filtering on dates, but having trouble filtering on anything, so present the following sample.

```
PS C:\>$defstrings = az policy definition list --management-group "mgsandbox"   # returns an array of strings
PS C:\>$def = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject ($defstrings -join "`n") -depth 99  # converts to an array of PSCustomObject
PS C:\>$def.count
2070
PS C:\>$sel = Where-Object -inputobject $def -FilterScript { $_.displayName -eq "Kubernetes cluster containers should not share host process ID or host IPC namespace" }
PS C:\>$sel.count
2070
PS C:\> $def[0].displayName -eq "Kubernetes cluster containers should not share host process ID or host IPC namespace"
False
```

While I might possibly find more than one hit on the displayName, there are clearly a non-zero set of displayNames that do *not* match the filter, yet the selection is getting all of them.

Any suggestions what's wrong with my syntax? It seems straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use an `-InputObject` *argument*** with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object); **instead, provide input *via the pipeline***:

```
# Use the pipeline to provide input, don't use -InputObject
$def | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.displayName -eq "Kubernetes cluster containers should not share host process ID or host IPC namespace" }
```

**In *most* cmdlets, the `-InputObject` parameter is a mere *implementation detail* whose purpose is to *facilitate pipeline input* and cannot be meaningfully used *directly***; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68836278/45375) for  more information, as well as [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for a discussion.

---

As for **what you tried**:

When you use `-InputObject`, an argument that is a collection (enumerable)  is passed *as a whole* to the cmdlet, whereas using the same *in the pipeline* cause its *enumeration*, i.e. the collection's *elements* are passed, *one by one*.

A simplified example:

```
# Sample array.
$arr = 1, 2, 3

# WRONG: array is passed *as a whole*
#        and in this case outputs *all* its elements.
#        -> 1, 2, 3
Where-Object -InputObject $arr { $_ -eq 2 }
```

That is, the script block passed to `Where-Object` is executed *once*, with the automatic `$_` variable bound to the *array as a whole*, so that the above is in effect equivalent to:

```
if ($arr -eq 2) { $arr }
```

Since `$arr -eq 2` evaluates to `$true` in a Boolean context (the `if` conditional), `$arr` *as a whole* is output (although on output it is enumerated), giving the impression that no filtering took place.

- The reason that `$arr -eq 2` evaluates to `$true` is that the `-eq` operator, among others, supports *arrays* as its LHS, in which case the behavior changes to *filtering*, by returning the *sub-array of matching elements* instead of a Boolean, so that `1, 2, 3 -eq 2` yields `@(2)` (an array containing the one matching element, `2`), and coercing `@(2)` to a Boolean yields `$true` (`[bool] @(2)`).<sup>[1]</sup>

Conversely, if the implied conditional yields `$false` (e.g., `$_ -eq 5`), no output is produced at all.

By contrast, if you use the pipeline, you'll get the desired behavior:

```
# Sample array.
$arr = 1, 2, 3

# OK: Array elements are enumerated, i.e. 
#     sent *one by one* through the pipeline.
#     -> 2
$arr | Where-Object{ $_ -eq 2 }
```

---

**Alternatively, you can *bypass* the pipeline by using the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)**:

Note: This requires collecting all input in memory first; however, especially with data already in memory, this approach performs better than the pipeline approach:

```
# OK:
# -> 2 (wrapped in a collection)
@(1, 2, 3).Where({ $_ -eq 2 })
```

Note: `.Where()` *always* outputs an array-like *collection*, even when only a *single* object matches the filter. In practice, however, that usually doesn't matter.

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion rules, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).</sup>