# Why can't I populate strongly-typed dictionaries with ForEach-Object unless the input object is provided via pipeline (rather than parameter)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.3

## Context

I'm aiming to gather info about the user's Java Runtime Environment in a script for use in checking that it meets certain requirements. I start with a variable named `JRE` that's cast as a list of strings, which becomes populated with info gathered about the Java Runtime Environment present (if any):

```
[List[String]] $Script:JRE = ($(Invoke-Expression -Command 'java --version' | Select-Object -Last 1) `
   -replace '(?:[\(\)]|Server VM|build)', '' `
   -replace '(?:(\d{2}\-Bit)|([\d\.\-\+]+)|(?:, (.+),) )', "`n`$1`n`$2`n`$3`n" `
   -replace ' {2,}', '' `
   -replace "`n+", "`n" `
) | Split-String -Separator "`n" # This works fine, but it doesn't make me feel fine.
```

Example result:

```
PS> $JRE[0..4]
OpenJDK
64-Bit
20.0.1+9-29
mixed mode
sharing
```

I then test against the contents of `JRE`…

- Is Java actually present? `($null -ne $JRE) -and ($JRE[0] -match '(java|OpenJDK)')`
- Is it reasonably up-to-date? `[Version]$JRE[2].Substring(0, $JRE[2].IndexOf('+')) -ge [Version]'20.0.0'`
- Is it the 64-bit build? `$JRE[1] -match '64'`

…and keep the results of these tests confined within a single variable, which is a strongly-typed dictionary named `JavaIs`:

```
[Dictionary[String, Boolean]] $Script:JavaIs = New-Object -TypeName 'Dictionary[String, Boolean]'
```

I need to populate `JavaIs`, and I decided to go with `ForEach-Object` for accomplishing this. **Here's where my question comes into play.**

## Trials, Expectations, Results

### The Parameter Way: ❌

What *doesn't* work is using the `InputObject` parameter to pass the hashtable to `ForEach-Object`. The result is that `JavaIs` receives a single, empty KV pair:

```
ForEach-Object -InputObject @{
   Extant = ($null -ne $JRE) -and ($JRE[0] -match '(java|OpenJDK)')
   Recent = [Version]$JRE[2].Substring(0, $JRE[2].IndexOf('+')) -ge [Version]'20.0.0'
   x86_64 = $JRE[1] -match '64' 
}.GetEnumerator() -Process {
   $JavaIs.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)
}

# For what it's worth, swapping the parameter order makes no difference:
ForEach-Object -Process { 
   $JavaIs.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)
} -InputObject @{
   Extant = ($null -ne $JRE) -and ($JRE[0] -match '(java|OpenJDK)')
   Recent = [Version]$JRE[2].Substring(0, $JRE[2].IndexOf('+')) -ge [Version]'20.0.0'
   x86_64 = $JRE[1] -match '64' 
}.GetEnumerator()
```

```
PS> $JavaIs

Key Value
--- -----
    False
```

### The Pipeline Way: ✔

What *does* work is providing the hashtable via pipe:

```
@{
   Extant = ($null -ne $JRE) -and ($JRE[0] -match '(java|OpenJDK)')
   Recent = [Version]$JRE[2].Substring(0, $JRE[2].IndexOf('+')) -ge [Version]'20.0.0'
   x86_64 = $JRE[1] -match '64' 
}.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object -Process {
   $JavaIs.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)
}
```

```
PS> $JavaIs

Key    Value
---    -----
x86_64  True
Extant  True
Recent  True
```

---

I'm perfectly okay with pipelining, but this piqued my curiosity. Why does using `-InputObject` fail in this scenario?

| Software | Version | Architecture |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PowerShell | 7.3.4 | x86_64 |
| Windows | 10.0.19045 | x86_64 |

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375). In your case, invoke `java --version` directly.

Comment: Your question is in effect a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72942282/45375  (which relates to `Where-Object`, but analogously applies to `ForEach-Object`), but it cannot be marked as such, because the answer there is neither up-voted nor accepted. The short of it is: using `-InputObject` explicitly, with an _argument_ - rather than implicitly _via the pipeline_ - is rarely meaningful; think of `-InputObject` as an implementation detail meant to facilitate pipeline input only.